# ¿Cómo iterar y obtener elementos en una lista de dos en dos (de forma alternativa)?

Tags: python, lista

Supongamos que tengo una lista

```
list1 = ["hola", "como", "estas", "vos?", "chau"]
```

yo quiero meter en otra lista digamos `list2` todos los elementos de la `list1` iterando de dos en dos. Es decir, que en ese ejemplo me quede:

```
list2 = ["como", "vos?"]
```

es muy simple la pregunta pero no me sale... quise hacer lo siguiente pero como ven ahí imprimo los números y no los strings de la lista:

Código erróneo:

```
max = len(list1).split(" ")
for x in range(0,max,2):
    lista2.append(x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@E. Betanzos explica correctamente que haces mal en tu código en su respuesta. No obstante puedes realizar lo que buscas de forma más simple y eficiente usando rebanado de listas (slicing):

```
>>> list1 = ["hola","como","estas","vos?","chau",]
>>> list2 = list1[1::2]
>>> list2
['como', 'vos?']
```

La sintaxis general es `[inicio:final:paso]`. En `[1::2]`, el 1 indica que corte la lista desde el segundo elemento (índice 1), el 2 indica que se tome cada dos elementos. Si no se especifica el índice inicial se toma desde el primer elemento, si no se especifica el índice final se toma hasta el último elemento y si no se especifica el paso se toman los elementos de uno en uno. Lo anterior es por tanto equivalente a `list1[1:len(list1):2]`

Comment: que facil asi, mil gracias!! y yo complicandome usando for y demas...

Answer (score 4):

Varias cosas a notar:

**1 - ¿Qué intentas hacer con?:**

```
max = len(list1).split(" ")
```

La función `len()` te permite conocer la longitud de la lista, por lo que retorna un número y a ese número le aplicas un `split()` como si de un `String` se tratara. Esto debería lanzarte un error como este:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Lo que debes hacer es simplemente guardar el resultado de la llamada a `len()` en la variable `max`.

```
max = len(list1)
```

**2 - En lista2 metes `x` en vez del elemento de list1**

El bucle `for` lo que hace, según lo defines, es generar un número entre 0 (inclusivo) y el valor que tenga la variable `max` (exclusivo) que asumamos es efectivamente la longitud de la lista `list1`, todo esto con un salto entre un valor geneerado y el siguiente de 2.

Hasta ahí todo bastante bien, pero si quieres comenzar a partir del elemento `"como"` en vez de 0 tienes que poner 1, ya que esta es la posición donde se encuentra dicho elemento. Luego tomas el elemento de `list1` en la posición `x` generada por el rango y es lo que metes a `lista2`.

Todo quedaría así:

```
max = len(list1)
for x in range(1,max,2):
    lista2.append(list1[x])
```

Comment: si max es por ejemplo el numero 10, eso te guarda en lista2 los numeros 2-4-6-8-10. yo quiero que me guarde el contenido de los strings de la list1 pero solo de dos en dos

Comment: Esta muy bien, agregaría a tu respuesta que no es buena práctica redefinir un nombre interno como `max` que es una función de Python, que `lista2` debería ser definida fuera del bucle, sino da error,  y no está de más  comentar la posibilidad de usar "slicing" para lograr exactamente lo mismo: `list1[1::2]`. Saludos.